# how to give resize support to my custom control when explicitly set width and height in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to give resizing behavior to my custom control when main window is resized even if i set both width and height explictly. How can i do this?

Just simple code here. Like this my custom control.

```
<Border Background="Red" Width="300" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="15"/>
```

Any one please provide your suggestion to me.

Comment: You cannot unless you override it in code. Instead you should place the control in a container if necessary, or use relative sizing/positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Simply dont give this control any Height and Width explicitly . And Place it in a Grid of Window that has RowDefinition with * Height and ColumnDefinition With * Width.

> **UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="debuggingusingreflector.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         >
<Grid>
    <TextBox  Background="Gray"/>
</Grid>
```

**Window.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="debuggingusingreflector.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:x1="clr-namespace:debuggingusingreflector"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Height="100" Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Red"/>
    <x1:UserControl1 Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can affect the `Width`/`Height` properties at runtime from the code. There is no problem either to perform these actions when the main form is being resized. Sample:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" SizeChanged="Window_resize">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="Red" Width="300" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="15" Name="borderName" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS

```
 private void Window_resize(Object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     borderName.Width = 0.5 * this.Width;
     borderName.Height = 0.5 * this.Height;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it not works. Currently i have overcome this by using ViewBox in control template which has binded to parent's ActualWidth.

Comment: @Muthalagu I am happy that you have found a different alternative, but this works fine. If you open a new C# WPF project and write this code (and change the 0.5 to any factor you want), you would see that the border is automatically resized (every time the size of the main form changes). You can put a break point on the Window_resize method  (and, logically, change the size of the main window) to confirm this.

Comment: @Muthalagu PS: logically, you have to update your XAML code (or do as suggested and create a new project from scratch and just copy this code) as far as your border does not have any name (and, logically, borderName. has no effect unless having a border called "borderName").